# laravel create one rule with query based on several fields from the form

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.8

I'm creating a simple reservation system and I need to check that car is available.
I'm gonna create a custom rule but I have following problems:
1. I need to pass an argument few values from form to passes method: date, time_form, time_to, car_id. The first and second question get excited because;
2. I'm not sure how and where to call that method in the controller if I have to use it in a few input's .
3. I suppose I need to create a query to check that car exist. In pure php I create query but I'm not sure that my "laravel" style query in god:

```php
$result = Reservation::where(function ($query) use ($request) {
            $query->whereBetween('time_from', [$request->input('time_from), $request->input('time_to')])
                ->orWhereBetween('time_to', [$request->input('time_from'), $request->input('time_to')]);
               })->where(function ($query) use ($request) {$query
            ->whereBetween($request->input('time_from'), ['time_from','time_to'])
            ->orWhereBetween($request->input('time_to'), ['time_from','time_to']);
               })
            ->where('date',$request->input('date'))
            ->where('car_id',$request->input('car_id'));
```

and pure php

```php
$sql1 = "select * from reservation 
        where ('$time_from' BETWEEN time_from AND time_to or '$time_to' BETWEEN time_from AND time_to) 
        and (time_from BETWEEN '$time_from' AND '$time_to' or time_to BETWEEN '$time_from' AND '$time_to')              
        and car_id = '$car_id'";
```

I'm newbie in laravel so I am asking you for understanding. I'm asking for some advice. Maybe is some better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code below:

```
$result = Reservation::query()
    ->where(function ($query) use ($request) {
        return $query
            ->whereBetween('time_from', [$request->input('time_from'), $request->input('time_to')])
            ->orWhereBetween('time_to', [$request->input('time_from'), $request->input('time_to')]);
    })
    ->where(function ($query) use ($request) {
        return $query
            ->whereRaw($request->input('time_from') . ' BETWEEN time_from AND time_to')
            ->orWhereRaw($request->input('time_to') . ' BETWEEN time_from AND time_to');
    })
    ->where('date', $request->input('date'))
    ->where('car_id', $request->input('car_id'));
```

Comment: Interesting, but I want to check it and I do not know how to call this method now in my store method in controller. Do you have any hints?

Comment: You can make get call that is `$result->get()` in order to get its output as collection. Also, there is a laravel helper function to print the output which is dd(). You can find more information regarding that [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-dd)

Comment: when i run query i get this error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ':00 BETWEEN time_form AND time_to or 09:00:00 BETWEEN time_for AND time_to' at line 1 (SQL: select * from `reservation` where (`time_from` between 07:00:00 and 09:00:00 or `time_to` between 07:00:00 and 09:00:00) and (07:00:00 BETWEEN time_from AND time_to or 09:00:00 BETWEEN time_from AND time_to ) and `date` = 2019-04-09 and `car_id` = 2)